# React: How to catch `onInput` event with `InputEvent` arguments on `contentEditable` div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, contenteditable, inputevent

I need to catch `historyUndo` and `historyRedo` from `InputEvent`. The problem is, my `contentEditable` div is giving me `FormEvent` not `InputEvent`.

```
const inputChanged = (e: InputEvent) => {
  //Error here because e is FormEvent type not InputEvent
  if(e.inputType === 'historyUndo' || e.inputType === 'historyRedo')
  {
    ....
  }
}

return <div contentEditable={true} onInput={(e) => inputChanged(e)}>
  ....
</div>
```

How can I catch `InputEvent` on div contentEditable?

Comment: Is the div wraps a `Form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is access the `nativeEvent` property of the event. Something similar to this.

```
const inputChanged = (e) => {
  if(e.nativeEvent.inputType === 'historyUndo' || e.nativeEvent.inputType === 'historyRedo')
  {
    ....
  }
}

return <div contentEditable={true} onInput={(e) => inputChanged(e)}>
  ....
</div>
```